# How to introduce date and time in log file

Tags: c, linux, datetime, logging

I have one daemon written in C. I am logging the events in a log file, but now I want to add date and time while writing event to log file. How can I achieve that?

Current log file:-

```
Event one occurred: result:
Event two occurred: result:
```

I want the log file to look like:-

```
Sep 14 11:35:55 Event one occurred: result:
Sep 14 11:35:55 Event two occurred: result:
```

My environment is C and Linux.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler, I am facing these alignment issues since long time, is there any reference page to ref and take care of myself?

Comment: You mean the layout in your question? When entering a comment, there's a help hyperlink; when entering a question or an answer, there's an orange question mark that provides help just above the typing area. Indenting by 4 spaces treats the material following as code; avoid tabs. Bullet lists have lines starting with a star or dash (`*` or `-`); you can nest them (sub-bullets are indented 2 or more spaces), and you can have code associated with them (prefixed with 8 spaces instead of just 4 though, for the first level bullets). Numbered lists have lines starting `1.` (the dot is crucial). Etc.

Comment: Better use [syslog(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/syslog.3.html) if your system has it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to look into using `date` and either `gmtime` or `localtime` to get the actual date and time.

Then `strftime` can format it for you.

Sample program follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main (void) {
    char buff[20];
    struct tm *sTm;

    time_t now = time (0);
    sTm = gmtime (&now);

    strftime (buff, sizeof(buff), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", sTm);
    printf ("%s %s\n", buff, "Event occurred now");

    return 0;
}
```

This outputs:

```
2011-09-14 04:52:11 Event occurred now
```

I prefer the use of UTC rather than local time since it allows you to tie together events from geographically separated machine without worrying about timezone differences. In other words, use `gmtime` rather than `localtime` unless you're *very* certain you won't be crossing timezones.

I also tend to prefer the `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` format since it's easier to sort than month names, vital for extraction and manipulation tools.

---

If you have an implementation that provides the optional bounds-checking functions (as per Appendix K of C11), you can probably use `gmtime_s` in preference. It allows you to specify your *own* buffer for receiving the result and is thus safer in re-entrant and/or threaded code.

To use that, you need to change your code to something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__ 1
#include <time.h>

int main (void) {
    char buff[20];
    struct tm sTm;

    time_t now = time (0);
    gmtime_s (&now, &sTm);

    strftime (buff, sizeof(buff), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", &sTm);
    printf ("%s %s\n", buff, "Event occurred now");

    return 0;
}
```

Although you should be aware that the folks at Microsoft have somehow managed to get the arguments for `gmtime_s` around the wrong way. You'll need to take that into account.

POSIX (and Linux) also provides a `gmtime_r` function which performs in the same way as the standard `gmtime_s` function (with the arguments in the *correct* order).

Comment: Does these library usage will resulted in portability issues?

Comment: Those are pure C89 functions - they are about as portable as you can reasonably hope for.  There are many other parts of your daemon that are less portable, that's for sure.

Comment: @Thangaraj: no, they're all defined in ISO C, about as portable as you can get :-)

Comment: @Thangaraj: if you are using an ISO C compiler then there will be no portability issues. If you're not using such a compiler, it really shouldn't be called C at all. `gcc` under `Linux` (as indicated by your tags) will be fine but the code should compile and run in any ISO-compliant environment.

Comment: Getting the error:
Error C4996 'gmtime': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using gmtime_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.

Comment: @PolinaC, the bounds-checking interfaces are an *optional* part of the standard, I prefer to stick with portability. In any case, Microsoft actually *don't* follow Appendix K in this case since they seem to be a bit dyslexic about the order of the parameters :-) I suspect their defence would be "we are not, nor never have been, a C compiler". However, for completeness, I'll add an addendum to cover this case.

Answer (score 11):

Adding my log functions, based on the answer by @paxdiablo. Using local time, but could use gmt just by modifying getFormattedTime()

common.h

```
// Returns the local date/time formatted as 2014-03-19 11:11:52
char* getFormattedTime(void);

// Remove path from filename
#define __SHORT_FILE__ (strrchr(__FILE__, '/') ? strrchr(__FILE__, '/') + 1 : __FILE__)

// Main log macro
#define __LOG__(format, loglevel, ...) printf("%s %-5s [%s] [%s:%d] " format "\n", getFormattedTime(), loglevel, __func__, __SHORT_FILE__, __LINE__, ## __VA_ARGS__)

// Specific log macros with 
#define LOGDEBUG(format, ...) __LOG__(format, "DEBUG", ## __VA_ARGS__)
#define LOGWARN(format, ...) __LOG__(format, "WARN", ## __VA_ARGS__)
#define LOGERROR(format, ...) __LOG__(format, "ERROR", ## __VA_ARGS__)
#define LOGINFO(format, ...) __LOG__(format, "INFO", ## __VA_ARGS__)
```

common.c

```
#include <time.h> // time_t, tm, time, localtime, strftime

// Returns the local date/time formatted as 2014-03-19 11:11:52
char* getFormattedTime(void) {

    time_t rawtime;
    struct tm* timeinfo;

    time(&rawtime);
    timeinfo = localtime(&rawtime);

    // Must be static, otherwise won't work
    static char _retval[20];
    strftime(_retval, sizeof(_retval), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", timeinfo);

    return _retval;
}
```

You can use them like this:

```
 LOGDEBUG("This is a log");
 LOGDEBUG("This is a log with params %d", 42);
```

Which produces the output:

```
2014-03-19 13:22:14 DEBUG [main] [main.c:54] This is a log
2014-03-19 13:22:14 DEBUG [main] [main.c:55] This is a log with params 42
```

Comment: what is implementation for "localtime"?

Comment: @PolinaC It's a `ctime` function, more info [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/localtime/)

Answer (score 5):

To get the current time you can use [`time.h`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time.h) for example...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{
  time_t now;
  time(&now);

  printf("%s", ctime(&now)); // use ctime to format time to a string.

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

You can also use [`strftime`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strftime) as suggested by paxdiablo for more time/date formatting possibilities.

Of course, for your case, the result of `ctime(&now)` will go into your log entry char array/string instead of `printf`.

Comment: It might be better (though basically equivalent) to use: `time_t now = time(0);`.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler - Academic really but yes, basically equivalent. Anyhow,  paxdiablo's answer is more complete than mine now, I just posted this to encourage him to add a code sample. ;)

Answer (score 2):

based on the answer by @inolasco, static variable is not thread safe. using local variable instead.

```
void getFormattedTime(char * const p, int sz) {
    time_t rawtime;
    struct tm* timeinfo;
    time(&rawtime);
    timeinfo = localtime(&rawtime);
    strftime(p, sz, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", timeinfo);
}

int mylog(const char* fmt, ...) {
    // TODO: log to file also.
    // TODO: create a new log file daily
    va_list argptr;
    va_start(argptr, fmt);
    vfprintf(stderr, fmt, argptr);//log to stderr
    va_end(argptr);
}


#ifdef _WIN32
#define __SHORT_FILE__ (strrchr(__FILE__, '\\') ? strrchr(__FILE__, '\\') + 1 : __FILE__)
#else
#define __SHORT_FILE__ (strrchr(__FILE__, '/') ? strrchr(__FILE__, '/') + 1 : __FILE__)
#endif

#define  ___LOG___(fmt,level,path, ...) do{\
    /* using local var and using a long name to avoid conflict*/ \
    char LAgGV3nzJsTholGvGL2eTNXmhsqYe___xxooxxoo___[24];\
    getFormattedTime(LAgGV3nzJsTholGvGL2eTNXmhsqYe___xxooxxoo___,\
        sizeof(LAgGV3nzJsTholGvGL2eTNXmhsqYe___xxooxxoo___));\
    mylog("%s [%s] [%s:%d] [%s] " fmt "\n", \
        LAgGV3nzJsTholGvGL2eTNXmhsqYe___xxooxxoo___, \
        level,\
        path,\
        __LINE__, \
        __func__, \
        ## __VA_ARGS__);\
}while(0)

#define  trace(fmt, ...) ___LOG___(fmt, "TRACE",__SHORT_FILE__, ## __VA_ARGS__)
#define  debug(fmt, ...) ___LOG___(fmt, "DEBUG",__SHORT_FILE__, ## __VA_ARGS__)
#define   info(fmt, ...) ___LOG___(fmt,  "INFO",__SHORT_FILE__, ## __VA_ARGS__)
#define   warn(fmt, ...) ___LOG___(fmt,  "WARN",__SHORT_FILE__, ## __VA_ARGS__)
#define  error(fmt, ...) ___LOG___(fmt, "ERROR",__SHORT_FILE__, ## __VA_ARGS__)
#define tracel(fmt, ...) ___LOG___(fmt, "TRACE",      __FILE__, ## __VA_ARGS__)
#define debugl(fmt, ...) ___LOG___(fmt, "DEBUG",      __FILE__, ## __VA_ARGS__)
#define  infol(fmt, ...) ___LOG___(fmt,  "INFO",      __FILE__, ## __VA_ARGS__)
#define  warnl(fmt, ...) ___LOG___(fmt,  "WARN",      __FILE__, ## __VA_ARGS__)
#define errorl(fmt, ...) ___LOG___(fmt, "ERROR",      __FILE__, ## __VA_ARGS__)
```

call them like this:

```
info("%s", "a log");
infol("%s", "a log");
```

produce:

```
2017-09-06 15:55:42 [INFO] [main.c:25] [main] a log
2017-09-06 15:58:08 [INFO] [d:\main.c:25] [main] a log
```